Azure cost management portal : Reservation Cost
Can anyone assist on how to extract azure cost (reservation part).
As you spend the cost will be coming in the reservation board (not cost management portal)
I checked this :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage?view=rest-cost-management-2023-11-01&tabs=HTTP
but the schema capture pre_tax_cost and this pre tax cost (has 0 value for the reservationdids)
But if I check in the reservation section, it has value associated to it which is greater than 0
Some cost present with the reservations as well.

In the Cost Analysis you have to set Pricing Model: Reservation

I strongly suggest you to export the Cost Analysis and have a look at the structure of the CSV:

Export 1 month or 1 week and have a look at the columns names. You will reuse those names in the API calls.
Otherwise another suggestion is to use Power BI to show the data.

But , do we have any API , that connects it ( as there are lot of resource group and its good to grab a group of resource group at once) , in the api we can pass like resource group / reservation_id  etc,

Frankly I would drop API calls and use CSV export instead: https://www.jeeja.biz/2023/02/06/how-to-download-azure-price-sheet/

okie, I will try both and let you know here.
